# ASP.NET MVC- How to pass data to another view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In View:

```
<table>
    @foreach(String key in map.Keys)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("page2", "page1")"> @key </a>
            <td>
        <tr>
    }
<table>
```

How can I pass the value of key to page2 and retrieve it in page2?

Answer (score 0):

You can add values to the query string using an overload of `Url.Action`:

```
Url.Action("page2", "page1", new { key = key })
```

This would add the value of `key` to the URL query string, denoted by the key `"key"`.

Comment: How can I retrieve the value of key on page2? ViewContext.RouteData.Values["key"] is returning null

Comment: @CS: In the ASP.NET MVC Framework that depends on how "page2" is defined.  I assume it's a controller action?  Does that controller action have a method parameter called `key`?  Can you add that parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Besides using passing value with Url.Action, You can also use Html.ActionLink.

```
@Html.ActionLink("some text here", "actionName", "controllerName", new { id = "1" }, null)
```

It gives you a link like the following.

```
<a href="/controllerName/actionName/1">some text here</a>
```